# Current in semidconductors

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics, conductors

I'm confused as to why when we measure current in an intrinsic semiconductor we calculate the summation of the current due to holes and that due to electrons as opposed to what's done in conductors. Here is the equation from my textbook for calculating drift current density due to flow of electrons: $$J_{n} = qn\mu_{n}E$$
and that of holes: $$J_{p} = qp\mu_{p}E$$
then the total drift current density is found by summing these two expressions: $$J = J_{p} + J_{n} = q(p\mu_{p}+ n\mu_{n})E$$

How come is it not of the electrons seldom or the holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a practical sense, holes behave like positive charges. It means you have both positive and negative charges, and so both contribute to the current.

In a more intutitive way, you have electrons moving, but this time the medium is not neutral anymore. In a conductor, you have a stream of electrones filling the place of the previous one as they move on. That's the only term for current.

However, here, if you take one electron out of its place, a hole is a place that becomes empty and it "wants" to be filled again. If the electron goes to the left, you've got an intensity towards the right. But, there is another term, because, if the electron moves to the left, all other electrons want to fill that ole, and so you've got so many electrons wanting to move to the left as well. Okay, so you can consider this second current as "many electrons", or you can see it as "a hole moving in the opposite way". That's why you consider the $\vec {J_p}$.

Comment: and that doesn't happen in conductors because electrons are mobile?

Comment: Conductors have the conduction and the valence bands overlapped. Electrons are already mobile without creating a hole. That's why you won't usually see "holes" in a metal, they rather move or rest, without creating holes. Normally you create currents in media with available electrons to fill the material.

Comment: Hole conduction most certainly can be seen in metals. Much depends on the full 3D band structure, and which parts are mostly electrons and which are holes. See any decent solid state physics book, such as Ashcroft and Mermin.

Answer (score 1):

Both holes and electrons contribute to current, according to how mobile they are. When an electric field is present, +ve holes move in one direction, -ve electrons move in the opposite direction. A +ve hole moving in one direction is equivalent to a -ve electron moving in the opposite direction. The total current is the sum of the two separate currents.

Conductors do not have holes. If they did, the same formula would apply as for semiconductors.

Comment: I thought they have holes only they are very difficult to identify as there's no gap between conduction and valence band. right?
I wish to know whether the mobility of conductors is the reason for not accounting for any current other than the electrons'.